# CKFinder 3 with Laravel 6 and Vuejs - 404 Error when accessing File Browser from vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js, routes, ckfinder

have this nearly working in being able to upload files to my laravel installation from CKEditor and the CKFinder file browser works from route myurl/ckfinder/browser.
But when i click on the image browser icon in CKEditor or open a CKFinder Popup from my vue file then the CKFinder File Browser popup opens but with a 404 error.
Uploading is ok and browser route is working - am sure is a config I am missing.

Current code:

editor: ClassicEditor,

```
    editorConfig: {

ckfinder: {
         uploadUrl: '/ckfinder/connector?command=QuickUpload&type=Images&responseType=json',
         openerMethod: 'popup',
        },
        toolbar: [ 'ckfinder', 'imageUpload', '|', 'undo', 'redo', 'removeFormat' ],

    },
```

Have got so close , but so far - Any help  very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Had been a long week and issue was caused by forgetting to add the following in the template file:

CKFinder.config( { connectorPath: '/ckfinder/connector' } );

Comment: Hi, there I am suffering on this topic as well.
Can you share your code in the index.html of VUE and the code in Laravel

Comment: Hi, the main problem was caused by not having the following in the Laravel layout file for the page. 

So make sure in /views/layouts/app.blade.php (or whatever your layout file is)
you have the following code

<script src="/js/ckfinder/ckfinder.js"></script> 
<script>CKFinder.config( { connectorPath: '/ckfinder/connector' } );</script>

Comment: Thanks for your explain, may I know your Vue is together with Laravel, or it is separately.